# How to create a LABELED horizontal threshold line in plotly js?

Tags: javascript, python, plotly

(Yes, I'm aware of [How to create a horizontal threshold line in plotly js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133372/how-to-create-a-horizontal-threshold-line-in-plotly-js) but that doesn't answer my question)

For Plotly Python, there's a useful method called [`add_hline`](https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-vertical-shapes/). With it I can add labelled horizontal line within the graph.
[image: Plotly Python plot]

When attempting to translate it into React JavaScript, I cannot find such methods and had to resort to:

1. Using [shapes](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/shapes/), which don't have labels [image: suboptimal plot using shapes]
2. Using [line chart overlays](https://plotly.com/javascript/text-and-annotations/), which don't extend to full plot area [image: suboptimal plot using line chart overlays]

Are there better ways to create a graph that can be easily created with Plotly Python in Plotly.js?

Answer (score 0):

The compiled JS for Plotly Python indeed have them as 2 separate entities, meaning they'll have to be programmed separately in JS.

[image]